# The average with listbox management

Tags: c#

```
int n = OgrencilerListBox.Items.Count;
double sum = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i < n;i++)
{
    sum = sum + double.Parse(OgrencilerListBox.Items[i].ToString());
}
double result = sum / n;
OrtalamaLabel.Text = result.ToString();
```

the error message says ( in 6th line)

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll

Comment: Obviously at least one of listbox items is not number. Can you show how you fill listbox with items?

Comment: ... and best to include a check if n > 0.

Comment: Please do not forget to upvote and check mark if you find your answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, clearly something being parsed is not a number. To fix this, why not use Double.TryParse(string,out double)?

This will alleviate attempting to figure out what is a number and what isn't.

```
double result = 0;
double sum = 0;

foreach(var item in OgrencilerListBox.Items){

    double parsedItem;

    string yourItem = item.ToString();

    bool parsed = Double.TryParse(yourItem,out parsedItem);

    if(parsed){
        sum+=parsedItem;
    }
    else{
       continue;
    }
}

result = sum/OgrencilerListBox.Items.Count;
```

[You can read more about Double.TryParse on the MSDN documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This means that at least one of your elements in `OgrencilerListBox.Items` cannot be parsed by `double.Parse` to a double.

Probably you use `,` instead of `.` as comma seperator, or it is no number at all.

One good way to avoid exceptions is to use the `.TryParse()` methods, for example [`Double.TryParse(string,out double)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you post example values of your ListBox, we can investigate further.